# How do I keep a bridge enabled on a bonded interface?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, centos6, bonding

I'm working on setting up a pair of CentOS 6.3 servers that will run a couple of KVM vms and have come across a problem setting up a bridge on a bond.

I am using Mode 4 (802.3ad) bonding on a pair of stacked Dell Powerconnect 5524 switches connecting to R320 servers. There are 2 links (1 to each switch) that form a Link Aggregation Group (802.3ad / LACP bonding). On top of the bond I have VLAN Tagging.

I've verified this is a problem on multiple other bonding modes so it isn't just a mode 4 issue.

I am testing what happens when 1 link is dropped (ie switch dies, cable breaks, etc).

If I don't have a bridge (for KVM), everything works fine, failover happens as expected.

If I have the bridge enabled, it works fine until failover (unplugging a cable). When failover happens /var/log/messages shows the slave link going down, followed within a second by:

```
kernel: br1: port 1(bond0.8) entering disabled state
```

The thing is /proc/net/bonding/bond0 shows the link is up as expected (simply with only 1 slave instead of 2). If I plug the cable back in it recovers and brings the bridge back to an enabled state.

I actually have tested this while a ping is occuring and if the timing is right a packet will actually leave the system after the link is lost, but *before* the disabled message occurs.

This disabled state I assumed was STP, but I have disabled STP on the bridge configuration and this issue still occurs.

```
brctl showstp br1
```

still shows the link as disabled when it is running without a slave.

I also switched between the nics in the server (I have 2x Broadcom & 4x intel). It doesn't matter which configuration I have.

Does anyone know of a way to force the bridge to stay enabled or why its detecting the bond as disabled, when it isn't?

Comment: Show the exact commands you used to set up the bond ifaces and the bridge.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into exactly the same issue with Fedora 16 on top of 2 x Dell R410s and a stucked pair of PowerConnect 6448s.

Bridged interface on top of a 802.3ad bond.

I'm experiencing exactly the same symptoms.

Here are the config files:

cat /etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf

> alias netdev-bond0 bonding
>
> alias netdev-bond1 bonding
>
> alias netdev-bond2 bonding

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

> Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
>
> Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
>
> Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
>
> MII Status: up
>
> MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
>
> Up Delay (ms): 0
>
> Down Delay (ms): 0
>
> 802.3ad info
>
> LACP rate: fast
>
> Min links: 0
>
> Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
>
> Active Aggregator Info:
>
> Aggregator ID: 23
>
> Number of ports: 2
>
> Actor Key: 17
>
> Partner Key: 629
>
> Partner Mac Address: 00:21:9b:b2:08:40
>
> Slave Interface: em1
>
> MII Status: up
>
> Speed: 1000 Mbps
>
> Duplex: full
>
> Link Failure Count: 0
>
> Permanent HW addr: 00:1e:c9:fd:f1:5e
>
> Aggregator ID: 23
>
> Slave queue ID: 0
>
> Slave Interface: em2
>
> MII Status: up
>
> Speed: 1000 Mbps
>
> Duplex: full
>
> Link Failure Count: 0
>
> Permanent HW addr: 00:1e:c9:fd:f1:60
>
> Aggregator ID: 23
>
> Slave queue ID: 0

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0

> DEVICE=br0
>
> ONBOOT=yes
>
> TYPE=Bridge
>
> BOOTPROTO=none
>
> IPADDR=10.100.100.101
>
> NETMASK=255.255.255.0
>
> IPV6INIT=no
>
> IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
>
> DHCPV6=no
>
> IPV6ADDR=fe80::21e:c9ff:fefd:f15e/64

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

> DEVICE=bond0
>
> USERCTL=no
>
> BOOTPROTO=none
>
> ONBOOT=yes
>
> BONDING_OPTS="miimon=100 mode=4 lacp_rate=1 xmit_hash_policy=1"
>
> BRIDGE=br0

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1

> DEVICE=em1
>
> HWADDR=00:1E:C9:FD:F1:5E
>
> ONBOOT=yes
>
> MASTER=bond0
>
> SLAVE=yes

Comment: "brctl stp br0 on" fixed the issue this time. I'll keep monitoring.